# Trouble using python re with the format option

Tags: python, regex

I have multiple files of the format **myfilexyz-200407171758.tar.gz**

(**myfilexyz**)-(**200407171758**).tar.gz

Group1 is a variable. 
Group2 can be of 12 to 14 digits.

Using variable substitution, I can get this working

`r = re.compile('(%s)-(\d){12,13}.tar.gz' %myvar)`

But if I were to try the newer format  method, I get into trouble

`r = re.compile('({})-(\d){12,14}.tar.gz'.format(myvar))`

*key '12,14' has no corresponding arguments*

Obviously the {12,14} is messing up format. Is there a way around this problem and still use the format method for substitution?

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings),

> If you need to include a bracing character in the literal text, it can be escaped by doubling:
>
> {{ and }}.

Use

```
'({})-(\d){{12,14}}.tar.gz'.format(myvar)
```

Also, format is older way of doing it. Use `f-string`

```
f'({myvar})-(\d){{12,14}}.tar.gz'
```

Why not concatenate directly?

```
myvar + '-(\d){{12,14}}.tar.gz'
```

Comment: Thanks Vishnu, That worked. I should have put some pressure on my brain before asking.